# Multiple values in a ::before pseudo element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Is it possible to set the content of a before pseudo element to contain more than one value ?
For example

```
content: attr(title) + attr(data-item)
```

outputting the title AND the data item ?

Comment: Not sure what's the exact output you want, if you want they to be concatenated **continuously** without space, just write `attr(title) attr(data-item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is...but you have specify a space between them if you want separation

```
content: attr(title)" "attr(data-item);
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6WGjc/3/)